# How I can separate and dynamic set html template for react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I do something like this:

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({...});

React.render(new SomeComponent({
    template: "SomeComponentTemplate1"
}, document.getElementById('example1'));

React.render(new SomeComponent({
    template: "SomeComponentTemplate2"
}, document.getElementById('example2'));
```

for rendering **SomeComponent** with different html templates **SomeComponentTemplate1** and **SomeComponentTemplate2**

Comment: What's a "template"? If you're using templates like Handlebars, mixing the two is more complex and I'd suggest you just pick one.

Comment: I need to be separated from the template code component. Because I want to use a different html and css for the same component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't have templates, it has components. Perhaps the distinction seems academic, it's crucial here.

A really basic way of rendering different markup depending on a prop is this:

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    if (this.props.type === "Greeting") {
      return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
    }

    if (this.props.type === "Farewell") {
      return <h1>Goodbye {this.props.name}</h1>;
    }

    return <div>Error</div>;
  }
});

React.render(
  <SomeComponent type="Greeting" name="DsXack" />,
  document.getElementById("example");
);
// => <h1>Hello, DsXack</h1>
```

You could make this cleaner by putting each "template" into its own function, but it's still not great.

A more idiomatic way would be to have a distinct component for each "template":

```
var Greeting = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
});

var Farewell = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <h1>Goodbye, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
});

var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return React.createElement(this.props.type, this.props);
  }
});

React.render(
  <SomeComponent type={Farewell} name="DsXack" />,
  document.getElementById("example");
);
// => <h1>Goodbye, DsXack</h1>
```

Because SomeComponent's `this.props.type` is the Farewell component (note the curly braces—we're passing the actual class, not a string), then we can pass it directly as the first argument to `React.createElement`, and then pass `this.props` as the second argument, so Farewell gets the same props.

Comment: Exactly! I can send the compiled js as a parameter for the component React. Thank U!